# Symfony console component: There are no commands defined in the "make" namespace

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I am trying to add few Symfony components in a legacy project in order to leverage it (I would rather avoid using the full Symfony framework). That works very well with http-foundation and routing. Now I am trying to add Doctrine and I would like to create entities thanks to the Symfony console component.

I have installed the following packages:

```json
    "require": {
        "symfony/error-handler": "^6.2",
        "symfony/http-foundation": "^6.2",
        "symfony/http-kernel": "^6.2",
        "symfony/routing": "^6.2",
        "symfony/console": "^6.2",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "^6.2",
        "symfony/orm-pack": "^2.2",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.13",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.7",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.2"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.48"
    }
```

And wrote the console file

```php
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
// bin/console

require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\Console\Application;

$application = new Application();

$application->run();
```

But I get this error message when creating an Entity:

```bash
$php bin/console make:entity Product 

There are no commands defined in the "make" namespace.
```

Here is the list of command I get with `console list`

```bash
php bin/console list
Console Tool

Usage:
  command [options] [arguments]

Options:
  -h, --help            Display help for the given command. When no command is given display help for the list command
  -q, --quiet           Do not output any message
  -V, --version         Display this application version
      --ansi|--no-ansi  Force (or disable --no-ansi) ANSI output
  -n, --no-interaction  Do not ask any interactive question
  -v|vv|vvv, --verbose  Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug

Available commands:
  completion       Dump the shell completion script
  help             Display help for a command
  list             List commands
```

How could I register the commands from Doctrine into Symfony console?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't you need to add https://symfony.com/bundles/SymfonyMakerBundle/current/index.html

Comment: did you try `APP_ENV=dev php bin/console make`

Comment: @DylanKAS Yes, I have installed it with composer already, but I still get ``There are no commands defined in the "make" namespace.``

@johnSmith I am not using the full Symfony framework, but just a few of its components

Comment: Do you want to not require symfony framework bundle ? Because i'm guessing the console without kernel does not work with the maker bundle

Comment: Yes, I mean not requiring the Symfony framework bundle so that I could keep the current structure of that project. The console works (I have edited my question above to show the results of ``php bin/console list``), just it does not find anything for make:* :)

Comment: The framework is required when using bundles.  No practical way around it.  Unless you really wanted to dive into things and register the maker command manually.  But judging from it's dependencies that would be quite an adventure.  You might consider creating a separate Symfony application just for generating entities and then copying them over to your legacy app.  And you also have a couple of doctrine bundles listed.  They won't work either.